# How to merge upstream/master into origin/master from a feature branch in Git?

Tags: git, rebase

As I am facing this difficulty a lot, I am wondering does git have a solusion for it or not.

- I have an Upstream repo.
- I have forcked it and named it `origin`.
- I have a `master` branch.
- I have a branch called `feature_1`.

I am in `feature_1` branch during development. I am following these steps when I want to rebase it:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git fetch upstream // To see is there any change although pull works as well
$ git merge upstream/master // in case there is a change
$ git push origin/master
$ git checkout feature_1
$ git rebase master
```

So, I know I am able to fetch upstream from feature_1 branch but I am wondering am I able to merge `upstream/master` into `origin/master` from feature_1 branch and then rebase it (without leaving feature_1 branch)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rebase `feature_1` on the latest remote version of the `master` branch, you can simply do the following:

```
git checkout feature_1       # switch to feature_1
git fetch upstream           # update upstream/master (and other tracking branches)
git rebase upstream/master   # rebase on latest master
```

I don't know what the remote `origin` means here, nor do I know what you intend by doing `git push origin/master`.  This looks like you are trying to push a remote tracking branch, which probably is not what you intend.

In any case, it *is* possible to rebase on a latest remote branch without actually leaving that branch.

Comment: Thanks Tim, `Remote` is company's repo. `Origin` is my forked one in order to send PR.

Comment: Again I don't know what you mean by `git push origin/master`, but I don't think this would change the bulk of my answer either way.

Comment: ah, ya, you are right. This is not neccessary in my rebase case, although I need it to keep record of changes (for creating a new branch). thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can merge `origin/master` into `master` in a different worktree (this requires a recent version of git, see `man git-worktree`).

```
worktree1 <feature_1> $ 
worktree2 <master>    $ git fetch && git merge origin/master
# this rebases onto new master: 2 worktrees share one set of branches
worktree1 <feature_1> $ git rebase master
```

Comment: Thanks Jokester. I guess you are checking out from `worktree1 <feature_1> $ ` to `worktree2 <master>    $`. I am wondering am I able to do `git fetch && git merge origin/master` from `feature_1` branch without checking out.

Comment: That does not require a checkout (I assume you wanted to avoid checkout). `worktree1` and `worktree2` are 2 worktrees (i.e. directories) for 2 branches respectively.